# Plot Quadratic Effects in multilevel model in R

Tags: r, multi-level, quadratic

I've calculated the following model:

```
a.Pfad<-lmer(FlowZ~MTsqZ+(1|VP04_01), data=MT)
```

with `MTsqZ` being a quadratic term.

I am looking for a way to plot this model: I want to see if there is an inverted u-shaped relationship between the variables. 
What is the best way to do this? As I am really unexperienced with any kinds of graphs in R, I am really looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the `sjPlot` package to plot effect sizes from `lmer` models. The function you want is `sjp.lmer` and if you want to plot the fixed effect slope of `MTsqZ`, you could type:

```
library(sjPlot)
sjp.lmer(a.Pfad, type = "fe.slope", vars = "MTsqZ")
```

Additional comment: From the looks of it, you have not modeled the relationship between `MT` and `FlowZ` as quadratic, since you only included the squared version of the variable.

**Edit:** This is how you can model the relationship as quadratic:

```
a.Pfad<-lmer(FlowZ~MT+I(MT^2)+(1|VP04_01), data=MT)
```

It is then possible to plot the relationship using `type = "poly"`:

```
sjp.lmer(a.Pfad, type = "poly", poly.term = "MT")
```

Comment: thank you! Hmmm...by using this function I really get a linear regression line. What should I have included to have the quadratic relationship? (Flow~MTZ+MTsqZ)? And what would the sjp-code look like then?

Comment: See above. Your solution would yield the same estimates, but it wouldn't be possible to pass results to `sjp.lmer`

Comment: By the way, it is entirely possible that the quadratic relationship doesn't look much different from a straight line, especially when you are zooming in on the range your observations lie in.

Comment: thank you! It's working now and the graph looks quadratic :)

Comment: For the latest _sjPlot_ version, you can also use the new `plot_model()` function: `plot_model(a.Pfad, type = "pred", terms = "MT")`.